# password protection - bcrypt vs. forced delay on login?

Tags: security, bcrypt

I have been doing a lot of research on safely storing passwords in a database, and [bcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) seems to be coming up all over the place as one of the most safe hashing algorithms, so I am probably going to use it for storing my website's passwords (written in PHP).  One of it's major selling points seems to be that it is extremely slow and therefore helps to slow brute force / dictionary attacks.  Literally every article I read mentions how bcrypt is great because it's slow and therefore prevents brute force attacks.

So, my question is: Can't I just manually make my code pause for a second or two after a failed login using PHP's `sleep()`?  Why is it so important that bcrypt is slow?  I am under the impression that I could use any encryption algorithm (let's assume that it's encrypted just as well as bcrypt), add a PHP sleep() on a failed login, and have just as good a defense against brute force / dictionary attacks as bcrypt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*bcrypt* and *forced delay on login* protect against two different attacks.

A forced delay on login adds protection against an **online attack**, where the attacker uses your login page to try different passwords.

*bcrypt* adds protection against **offline attacks**, where the attacker has gained access to your password hashes and can try hashes without using the login page.

Comment: That clears things up a lot, I see where my confusion was.  Thanks

Comment: Forced delay also prevents a CPU *denial-of-service* attack against your servers. BCrypt is **intentionally** expensive to compute. Letting a user-agent trigger your web-server into validating hundreds, thousands, or millions of passwords, without a break, can starve your server of CPU resources.